# text going outside of fluid div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to make a fluid responsive template with Bootstrap but it appears everytime the page is extended with a lot of text inside a header or paragraph, or when there is a lot of text in a heading or paragraph in general within a div thats class is a fluid row.... it goes outside the div pushing the other div down. How do I fix this? http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/4238/screenshot20130228at114.png

```
 ![<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="div-1">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Page heading <small>Subheading</small>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <span class="span3">
          <h1 class="heading">Headingaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        </span>
        <span class="span6">
          <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </span>
        <span class="span3">
          <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this using http://jsfiddle.net or else please put the related css as well

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple fix...

Just add the following CSS:

```
.row-fluid {
    word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

Load this jsFiddle example and then hit run. Just stretch the results box to see it clearly.

[jsFiddle example to fix the non-wrapping long words](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisallenmoore/5fdd6/)

Also note that in your example, you have a long word with no breaks, this is why it's really running over the edge. Most words probably don't run that long. But, say you had the word "Supercalifragelousexpialidocious" this fix might be needed. :)

Comment: But you would think tht since it's contained in the DIV it would just automatically break as it's resized considering it's INSIDE a div . I don't get why it's running over is the thing, I'll give what you said a shot! Thanks.

Comment: I feel ya on that one. Seems like it should work that way, but the div won't automatically break a whole word to wrap it.  This is where the word-wrap property comes in. It allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

use this css code. it will break line from where the container boundary ends

```
.test2
{
 word-break:break-all;
}
```